# Chain of apache reverse proxies

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-2.2

We have reverse web proxy on Apache2 that proxies requests to the remote webserver using URL http://server1 that gets content proxied from http://realserver1
  Now I am trying to add another site to webproxy that does the same, the difference is that remote server already runs Apache as a reverse proxy (for the java application on the same host but different port).
 I.e. webproxy serves URL http://server2 that gets content proxied from http://realserver2, which in turn gets its content from http://localhost:someport
Now I would expect that this setup would just work, however it does not.
Instead I am being redirected to http://realserver2.Any idea what ai am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Code can be seen in snipt.net/search?q=apache+reverse+proxies+chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding follwing in webproxy fixed it
ProxyPreserveHost On

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a `ProxyPassReverse` directive for each `ProxyPass` already in place.

Check that you're not performing any erroneous rewrites (with flag R in particular) or standard redirections on realserver2.

Also: post the relevant bits of configuration so we can have a look at them.

Comment: sorry snipt.net/search?q=apache+reverse+proxies+chain